# Expose REST As SOAP API using WSO2 Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have to expose a REST API as SOAP API by using integration Studio .
I tried to use PayloadFactory mediator to convert SOAP Payload to JSON Payload because my Backend is REST using this Configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/test" name="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>

            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{&#xd;
  "_poststudent": {&#xd;
    "name" : "$1",&#xd;
    "school": "$2",&#xd;
    "grade": $3&#xd;
  }&#xd;
}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//root/_poststudent/name"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//root/_poststudent/school"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//root/_poststudent/grade"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="http://ITMTNP219BS5:8290/services/RESTDataService/student">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

but i got an exception "INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR" .I tried to pass only XML Payload it works so i have to remove the SOAP Envelope and body from the payload .Is there any solution to do that ?

This is the payload that user should send :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<root>
   <_poststudent>
      <name>oussama</name>
      <school>essat</school>
      <grade>20</grade>
   </_poststudent>
</root>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is the payload that my backend is accept :

```
<root>
   <_poststudent>
      <name>oussama</name>
      <school>essat</school>
      <grade>20</grade>
   </_poststudent>
</root>
```

Comment: Add the Payload you send in and the Payload you expect the API to produce. `INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR` is comig from the DSS service.

Comment: I have updated my question with the payload.

Comment: Do you want to conver the SOAP message to a XML?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to convert the SOAP message to XML just set the following property before the call mediator.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: the error still even i have added this property

Comment: @OussamaNairi Can you enable wirelogs and share the logs, also add your DS Configs.